# How to create a json file from csv file where csv file has following format

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, csv

```
Name,abc
Title,teacher
Email,abc.edu
Phone,000-000-0000
Office,21building
About,"abc is teacher"
Name,def
Title,plumber
Email,plumber@plumber.com
Phone,111-111-1111
Office,22building
About,"The best plumber in the town"
Name,ghi
Title,producer
Phone,333-333-3333
Office,33building
About,"The best producer"
```

Comment: That's not a format, just an example. Do we know where one record ends and the next start? In other words, where does the description of one person end and the next start?

Comment: Also, this is far too broad. What have you considered and tried so far? Where are you stuck? We're not going to do your homework, we want to help people be able to do their homework themselves...

Comment: You may capture first element of each row and make it as Key of a dictionary entry and second element of each row as Value of the dictionary entry.
Then you can convert this dictionary to JSON by using `json_object = json.dumps(dictionary, indent = 4) `

Answer (score 0):

I would use `pandas` library to read the .csv (*foo.csv* in this example) data and then convert it to json using `to_json`.

In this case you have a dictionary

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('aaa.csv', header=None, index_col=0, squeeze=True)\
    .to_json(orient='columns')
```

If you want to export a .json file

```
import pandas as pd
with open('exported_file.json', 'w') as f:
    pd.read_csv('foo.csv', header=None, index_col=0, squeeze=True)\
        .to_json(f, orient='columns')
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the CSV-file containes a sequentional records about personal in a format `"Label,Value"` and you'd like to reorganize it in the separated records for each person with labels along the second dimension as a column names. The output is going to be stored as a JSON-file.

If this is the case, then we can use `pandas.DataFrame.pivot` to change the scructure of data. But before that we have to group labes by person. For this purpose, I will assume that the `Name` label is obligatory for each person, and each unique label appears at most once between names:

```
data = '''Name,abc
Title,teacher
Email,abc.edu
Phone,000-000-0000
Office,21building
About,"abc is teacher"
Name,def
Title,plumber
Email,plumber@plumber.com
Phone,111-111-1111
Office,22building
About,"The best plumber in the town"
Name,ghi
Title,producer
Phone,333-333-3333
Office,33building
About,"The best producer"'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), names=['label','value'])
df['grouper'] = (df['label'] == 'Name').cumsum()
df = df.pivot(index='grouper', columns='label', values='value')
```

Having this data we can save it as:

```
df.to_json('test.json', orient='records', lines=True)
```